# NoSuchMethodError in Jetty with Spring Data Mongo custom repository

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a small web application in development using Maven, Spring MVC and Spring Data Mongo. I am getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when one of my Controllers attempts to access a method defined in a custom repository. The same method works fine when exercised via a JUnit 4 test extending AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests and using a near-identical XML configuration file.

Standard repository:

```
public interface IndividualRepository extends MongoRepository<Individual, String>, IndividualRepositoryCustom {
    ...
}
```

Custom interface:

```
public interface IndividualRepositoryCustom {
    Individual findByIdentifier(String identifierType, String identifierValue);
}
```

Custom implementation:

```
public class IndividualRepositoryImpl implements IndividualRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public Individual findByIdentifier(String identifierType, String identifierValue) {
        String locator = String.format("identifiers.%s", identifierType);
        return mongoTemplate.findOne(query(where(locator).is(identifierValue)), Individual.class);
    }

}
```

dataaccess-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.myco.dataaccess"/>

    <mongo:mongo host="mongo.myco.com" port="27017"/>

    <mongo:db-factory dbname="test" mongo-ref="mongo"/>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg value="test"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

In my JUnit test I have (excerpt):

```
@Autowired
private IndividualRepository individualRepo;

...

List<Individual> foundList = individualRepo.findAll();
assertNotNull(foundList);
assertTrue(foundList.size() > 0);

Individual found = individualRepo.findByIdentifier("someid", "123456");
assertNotNull(found);
assertEquals("Bob", found.getFirstName());
```

The test passes fine, calling both findAll() (standard Repository method) and findByIdentifier() (custom method). The latter fails with NoSuchMethodError when called by a Controller running in a web application in Jetty, while the same Controller can call findAll() with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be nothing to do with Spring Data, but an issue with the way I was using the maven-jetty-plugin with my multi-module build.

Basically, I was running `mvn jetty:run` for my web module which had a dependency on my dataaccess module (where my JUnit tests lived). As I was rebuilding the project with `mvn clean package`, the latest versions were not being placed in my local repo, and therefore were not being picked up by the `mvn jetty:run` process running alongside my build process. Problem was solved by building with `mvn clean install`.

So, as usual, the error message was spot on - the method indeed did not exist in the version of the JAR that Jetty was being supplied.